# Proper error handling with windows service that loads external assembly/dll

Tags: c#, reflection, windows-services

I have a windows service that loads a bunch of 'plugins' that are just .dll files.  It uses reflection to do this:

```
try
{
   Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("myPlugin.dll");
   Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();
   foreach (Type t in types)
   {
      Type[] ifaces = t.GetInterfaces();

      foreach (Type f in ifaces)
      {
          if (f.Name == "MyPlugin")
          {
              pType = t;
              break;
          }
      }
      if (pType != null)
          break;
   }
}
catch
{
   AddToLog("Failed");
}
obj = Activator.CreateInstance(pType);

object[] Parameters = new object[1];
Parameters[0] = _pluginName;

try
{
    pType.InvokeMember("InitializePlugin",
                      BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                      null,
                      obj,
                      Parameters);

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    AddToLog(_pluginName + " - InitializePlugin error: " + ex.Message);
}
```

Problem I am having is that if the 'InitializePlugin' method with the external dll fails, it is not caught with the try/catch in the code above and ends up crashing the whole service.  Is there a better way to handle errors that occur in an externally loaded assembly like this?

Comment: *Never* use LoadFile(), use LoadFrom().  You cannot catch exceptions that are raised in a thread that was started by the plug-in.

Comment: I tried to use LoadFrom() but when exception occurs (at line 4, assembly.GetTypes()) the exception is not caught and the service stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use a catch block with no exception.  Not all exceptions have a type.

```
try
{

}
catch(Exception ex)
{

}
catch
{
}
finally
{
}
```

Comment: Yes, but all exceptions derive from `Exception`.  So an empty catch will catch the same exceptions as a catch that specifies the type of exception as `Exception`.

Comment: When i put in an additional catch with no arguments Visual Studio gives a warning that there is already a catch block that catches all exceptions so it sounds like juharr is right.

Comment: So I changed the original catch block to use no arguments and it worked.  So CrazyDart, you are right, but not if you have more than one catch block.  Thanks guys.

Comment: @CrazyDart Can you elaborate on exceptions that do not derive from `Exception`?

Comment: I am not going to pretend to know a lot about this when I dont.  Years ago I was working on some code that used ESRI libs and our app was crashing from these unhandled exceptions.  I researched it and found that there are exceptions that are not handled by the .Net framework but are handled by C#, and this is how they are caught.  From that time any time I see this situation arise, I give the solution, I get a tung lashing from those who know better... they try it, and come back with a bewildered look on their face when it actually does work.  Perhaps I will take the time to solve the mystery.